# Pass function as argument in xml action

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

What I'm basically trying to do is to call a function through an action button in Powershell's XML template for Windows' Toast Notification.

It works for strings and other variables but doesn't for functions. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<action content="Install now" imageUri="$PSScriptRoot\install.png" arguments=""function:$Get-Version"" activationType="protocol" />
```

Comment: You can't run arbitrary code from a toast notification, you have to supply a URI for which a protocol handler is registered on the machine - for example, pass `https://something` as `arguments` <-- launches web browser

Comment: I need a way to somehow pass a function when the button is clicked.